# UITests check download progress

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using UITests for check download progress.

My code in swift:

```
let activityIndicator = app.activityIndicators.elementBoundByIndex(0)

while activityIndicator.exists == true {          
    sleep(1)
}
```

But when the download process is finished and activityIndicator goes from the screen, application still returns true and does not come out of the method while.